# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Area URL Routing Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 application. With 2 Areas:

- Auth - handles all the authentication etc
- Management - area for property management

In the Management Area I  have a ManagementController and a PropertyController. The ManagementController does nothing, it only has a simple Index ActionResult than return a view.

The PropertyController has an Index ActionResult that returns a view with a list of properties as well as an Edit ActionResult that takes a propertyId as parameter. In the Property Index view i have a grid with the list of properties and an option to edit the property with the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Property", new { id = item.PropertyId })
```

In theory this should redirect to the Edit ActionResult of my Property Controller,however it redirects to the Index ActionResult of my ManagementController. My ManagementAreaRegistration file looks like this:

```
context.MapRoute(null, "management", new { controller = "management", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute(null, "management/properties", new { controller = "Property", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute(null, "management/properties/Edit/{propertyId}", new { controller = "Property", action = "Edit" });
```

And my global.asax's RegisterRoutes like this:

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

What am I missing, why would it redirect to the wrong controller and action? 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your route you defined a parameter called propertyId not id:

```
context.MapRoute(null, "management/properties/Edit/{propertyId}", new { controller = "Property", action = "Edit" });
```

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Property", new { propertyId = item.PropertyId })
```

Comment: I've tested this route and it works: http://localhost/management/properties/edit/1

Comment: ok, by following both suggestions, e.g. specifying the Area, and changing Id to propertyId...it works!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You might need to specify the area in your route values parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Property", new { id = item.PropertyID, area = "Management" }, new { })
```

Based on the constructor used for this call, you need to specify the last parameter, htmlAttributes, which, for your purposes, would be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I receive the same result, it still redirects to the ManagementController's Index result, not the PropertyController's Edit actionresult

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using constraints.
For example my default route in the Global.asax is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default",
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
new string[] { typeof(MyProject.Controllers.HomeController).Namespace });
```

Then in my area registration:

```
context.MapRoute(
"Search_default",
"Search/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
new string[] { typeof(MyProject.Areas.Search.Controllers.HomeController).Namespace }
            );
```

This means I get {AppName}/ as well as {AppName}/Search/Home and both work a treat.

Answer (score 0):

From any Area to Home do following

```
Url.Action("Details", "User", new { @id = entityId, area = "" })
```

From Home to any Area

```
Url.Action("Details", "Order", new { @id = entityId, area = "Admin" })
```